# Deploy a website with database that is created using VS 2010

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, deployment, webserver

We are creating a website using VS 2010 (c#) and I was wondering, after were done with our online inventory system, how are we going to deploy it? I wanted to know the following:

1. The things that we need like the web hosting site, web server, anything that we need to pay for, can you give some suggestions.
2. And the method for deployment. The right address/URL, port what so ever.

Please help me out, it's for our thesis. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has a deployment tool (Build => Publish). From here you can specify if you're deploying to a server via the Web, FTP, File System or Front Page Server Extensions (FPSE).

[This blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/06/06/visual-studio-2010-1-click-publishing.aspx) contains some info about it.

If I'm deploying to a server on our network I use the File System deployment, though for remote servers you're probably best using the Web or FTP method.

Can't help you with hosting costs / recommendations, this probably isn't the best place to ask about them.

Hope this helps.